# Blender not opening (Mac OS)

Tags: error

Blender won't start up on my computer anymore. I have tried to uninstall and download different versions of Blender, but nothing seems to work.

I installed a plugin that didn't seem to work with my version of Blender and after that I could not open up Blender again.

There seems to be a lot of solutions for this for PC, but I haven't been able to solve it for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the [answer here](https://blenderartists.org/t/2-8-wont-open-on-macos-mojave/1176135/5).
I needed to open *Terminal* and delete a *userpref.blend* file.

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Blender/3.3/config
```

(or whatever version of Blender you are using)

Type `ls` to see the *userpref.blend* file.
To delete the file type `rm userpref.blend`